# C++ nested lambda bug in VS2010 with lambda parameter capture?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda, c++11

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, which apparently has some buggy behavior on lambdas, and have this nested lambda, where the inner lambda returns a second lambda wrapped as a std::function (cf. ["Higher-order Lambda Functions" on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293599.aspx#higherOrderLambdaExpressions)):

```
int x = 0;
auto lambda = [&]( int n ) 
{ 
    return std::function<void()>( 
        [&] // Note capture
        { 
            x = n; 
        } 
    ); 
};

lambda( -10 )(); // Call outer and inner lambdas

assert( -10 == x ); // Fails!
```

This compiles but fails at the assert. Specifically, n in the inner lambda is uninitialized (0xCCCCCCCC), but x is successfully modified to its value. If I change the inner lambda's capture clause to "[&,n]", the assert passes as expected. Is this a bug with VS2010 or have I not understood how lambda capture works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a bug, since `n` goes out of scope after lambdas return statement, thus the capture by reference is invalidated by the time you use it.

```
int x = 0;
auto lambda = [&]( int n ) 
{ 
    return std::function<void()>( // n is local to "lambda" and is destroyed after return statement, thus when you call the std::function, the reference capture of n is invalid.
        [&]
        { 
            x = n; // Undefined behaviour
        } 
    ); 
};

auto tmp = lambda(-10); 
// n is no longer valid
tmp(); // calling tmp which uses reference of n which is alrdy destroyed.

assert( -10 == x ); // Fails!
```

Comment: I actually think the compiler should be able to warn of this.

Comment: @mlimber : Keep in mind that VC++ 2010 implemented lambdas pre-[N2927](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf), so it's going to have many "incorrect" behaviors related to nested lambdas.

Comment: Although in this particular case (with the return) you may be correct, nested Lambda's do incorrectly lose scope in VS2010: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/537366/c-nested-lambda-functions-lose-scope Microsoft claims to have applied a fix for this in their implementation which we'll see in a future release.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to the case of just returning a simple reference.  The thing that caught you was the compiler did not issue an warning.  So it is not a bug in the compiler, it is just a lack of a warning.

```
std::function<int()> F(int n)
{
    return [&]{ return n; };  //no warning
}
int& F2(int n)
{
    return n; //warning
}
```